# Find the derivative of the semicircle $y= \sqrt{169-x^2}$ and sketch the semi-circle

Tags: calculus

We weren't taught this in class and I've tried to search it up but can't find the answer.

> The derivative of $y=\sqrt{169 - x^2}$ is equal to $- x/\sqrt{169-x^2}$, but how do you find the radius of the semi-circle and sketch it?

Comment: This is the top half of the circle $x^2+y^2=169$, so centre the origin and radius $\sqrt{169}=13$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: You simply posted a complete solution with answer?

Comment: Please google for StackExchange LaTeX guide to see how to format your math equations nicely.

Comment: @user21820:  I expected (this time mistakenly) that the question would be quickly closed, and wanted to be of help. By my lights the sentence in the comment was not a complete solutio.  I would agree that writing that $\sqrt{169}=13$ was not a good idea.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Ah no wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $y=\sqrt{169-x^2}=(169-x^2)^{1/2}$ its derivative is determined by the chain rule as follows $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(169-x^2)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}(169-x^2)^{1/2-1}(-2x)=-x(169-x^2)^{-1/2}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{169-x^2}}$$
Now, compare the given equation of circle : $$y=\sqrt{169-x^2}$$ $$y^2=169-x^2$$ $$x^2+y^2=169$$  with standard form: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ having center at the origin $(0, 0)$ & a radius $r$, thus we get $$\text{radius of semicircle }=\sqrt{169}=13$$

Since, you have not mentioned the interval of the variable $x$, hence we have

The semicircle will be on the right side of y-axis for all $0\leq x\leq 13$

The semicircle will be on the left side of y-axis for all $-13\leq x\leq 0$

Answer (score 0):

If $y = \sqrt{169-x^2}$, then $y^2 = 169 - x^2$. Can you rearrange this to get something that looks like Pythagoras theorem? That would tell you where $(x,y)$ must be to satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a semicircle is given by:
$$y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
where $r$ is the radius. Hence in your case the radiu13*13
s is:$$\sqrt{169}=13$$